Не показывает изображение
<img src="@Url.Content("C:\Users\1\source\repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Pages\images\Photo1.png")" Height="200" Width="300">

если ввести вот так, то браузер прекрасно показывает изображение, но VisualStudio
CS1009  Нераспознанная escape-последовательность
<img src="@Url.Content("C:/Users/1/source/repos/WebApplication5/WebApplication5/Pages/images/Photo1.png")" Height="200" Width="300">

а вот так не показывает изображени.
помогите пожалуйста

src="~/Pages/images/Photo1.png". И изображения (в данном случае папка Pages) должны быть в wwwroot папке (документация)...

Не помогло, перенес папку images в папку wwwroot, но найти не может

Документацию прочитайте, пожалуйста, там все сказано как и что делать. Если у вас wwwroot/images/file.png, то путь указывается как ~/images/file.png.

Требуется разрабатывать проект всё время в одной версии Visual Studio, в другой Visual Studio другой .NET и созданный проект работает всегда в одной и той же версии VisualStudio или придётся переписывать заново.

@DmitriySidyakin Ой ну и чушь вы написали... Каждая новая версия студии без труда поддерживает все старое. По вашей логике, если я сейчас захочу запустить проект условно 2010 года, я обязан качать древнюю студию, чтобы запустить его? Не кажется... Странным? Речь наверно про .NET? Вот его смена да, может повлиять на код, особенно если делается понижение версии. В ASP проектах обновление .NET также может потребовать ряда изменений. Но студия... Она без труда запустит любой проект и любой версии.
